# Closing applications / windows in TCL

Tags: tcl

I wish to know how to close an open application in TCL specifically (the TK commands aren’t installed on my system so I can’t use destroy).

I am running a script which launches an image viewer which also has command line options Currently I have:

```
exec cmd /c ".\image_viewer -specified_option"
```

Since this is what I’d put into the command line to run the viewer with the added option.

It then launches a window with the title “`image_viewer.exe`”.

How do I get it to close the window above and continue with its other steps?

Also I need to know how to do a screen capture and save for that image. Can you screen capture a specific / designated portion of the screen?

Comment: So, this is on Windows? There's probably something in the TWAPI extension, but I'm on the wrong platform to experiment and I don't know the extension enough to help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the command into the backround, you can get the process id back:

```
set pid [exec cmd /c ".\image_viewer -specified_option" &]
```

Then, for example kill the process after 10 seconds:

```
proc killpid { pid } {
   if { $::tcl_platform(platform) eq "windows" } {
      set cmd "taskkill.exe /f /fi \"pid eq $pid\" 2>nul"
      exec -ignorestderr -- {*}$cmd 2>@1
   } else {
      exec kill $pid
   }
}

after 10000 [list killpid $pid]
```